# Adding a subplot that doesn't share an x axis when others do

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to add a subplot onto the bottom of a figure of subplots. The issue I've got is that all of the first set of subplots want to share their x axis, but not the bottom one.

`channels` are the subplots that want to share the x axis.

So how can I add a subplot that does not share the x axis?
This is my code:

```
def plot(reader, tdata):
    '''function to plot the channels'''

channels=[]
        for i in reader:
        channels.append(i)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(channels)+1, sharex=False, figsize=(30,16), squeeze=False)
    plot=0
    #where j is the channel name
    for i, j in enumerate(reader): 

        y=reader["%s" % j]
        ylim=np.ceil(np.nanmax(y))
        x=range(len((reader["%s" % j])))
        ax[plot,0].plot(y, lw=1, color='b')
        ax[plot,0].set_title("%s" % j)
        ax[plot,0].set_xlabel('Time / s')
        ax[plot,0].set_ylabel('%s' % units[i])
        ax[plot,0].set_ylim([np.nanmin(y), ylim+(ylim/100)*10])
        plot=plot+1

    ###here is the new subplot that doesn't want to share the x axis###
    ax[plot, 0].plot()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

This code does **NOT** work because they are shareing the x-axis of the last subplot. The length of channels changes dependant onn what I specify earlier in the code.

Is it a valid option to use `add_subplot` somehow, ever though I don't have a constant number of channels?

thanks so much for any help

**EDIT**
Image for Joe:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest to use `fig.add_subplot` directly in this case.

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 8))

# Axes that share the x-axis
ax = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 1)
axes = [ax] + [fig.add_subplot(4, 1, i, sharex=ax) for i in range(2, 4)]

# The bottom independent axes
axes.append(fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 4))

# Let's hide the tick labels for all but the last shared-x axes
for ax in axes[:2]:
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

# And plot on  the first subplot just to demonstrate that the axes are shared
axes[0].plot(range(21), color='lightblue', lw=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: when I run this code, the scale doesn't change to plot the range, my shared axis scale stays at 0.06. I can show you an image, but not sure where to post it

Comment: @AshleighClayton - You can either add it to your question or just post it on imgur (or a similar image sharing site) and add a link as a comment.  I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: I literally copied your code completely just to test it. I'll put the image in my question. thanks for the help

Comment: @AshleighClayton - Are you sure you didn't zoom in interactively?  Regardless, it's still demonstrates what you asked. The first three x-axes are shared while the last one is independent. However, I may very well be misunderstanding your question. (?)

Comment: Thanks @Joe Kington. I'm getting it now thanks! Was having difficultly as I have to loop when plotting and my x axes are dates! But think I've got it now